# mat-option selected base on if condition

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2, angular-ng-if

I want to make a mat-option pre checked base on an `if` condition.

```html
<div class='form'>
  <mat-form-field color='accent'>
  <!-- if UserAccount is not null, 'Yes' should be pre selected -->
    <mat-select class='form-control' placeholder='user account exists' [(ngModel)]='UserAccountExists' name='UserAccountExists' required value=! data.UserAccount.trim() ? "Yes" : "No">
      <mat-option [value]='"Yes"'>Yes </mat-option>
      <mat-option [value]='"No"'>No </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngIf='formControl.invalid'>{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<!-- if "Yes" is selected, this field is 'required' -->
<div class='form'>
  <mat-form-field color='accent'>
    <input matInput #inputstate class='form-control' placeholder='Username' [(ngModel)]='data.username' name='Username' required>
    <mat-error *ngIf='formControl.invalid'>{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

1. The first `<div>` : If the `UserAccount` exists, `"Yes"` should be prechecked.
2. If `"Yes"` is selected, in the second `<div>`, `<input>` is `required`

Can someone please help?

Thank you

Comment: Consider using `camelCase` instead of `PascalCase` for variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<mat-select class='form-control' placeholder='user account exists' [(ngModel)]='UserAccountExists' name='UserAccountExists' required>
  <mat-option value="Yes">Yes </mat-option>
  <mat-option value="No">No </mat-option>
</mat-select>

...

<input matInput class='form-control' placeholder='Username' [(ngModel)]='data.username' name='Username' [required]="UserAccountExists === 'Yes'">
```

In your Component, once you fetched your data :

```
this.UserAccountExists = !!data.UserAccount ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

Comment: it works! Thank you! I slightly changed a bit according to my Component. But principally it works!